# How to stop asp.net button from being double clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, double-click

Ok, let me preface this question with the fact that I have read through about all the articles on this website and tried the majority of these solutions.

I have a button that has a server side event.  This server side event has a (handles btnSave_click).

My first attempt was of course this. :

```
btnSave.enable = false
```

This was of course not fast enough.

Then I tried this. :

```
btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.disabled=true;");
```

and this. :

```
btnSave.Attributes.Add("onclick", " this.disabled = true; " + ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btnSave, Nothing) + ";")
```

This did not work, of course then I tried a bunch of different jquery and javascript via the OnClientClick event.  This did not work either, but from what I could see it was due to the fact that I have that server side event firing also, I wasn't hitting my functions during stepthrough.  As you can see I have spent a ton of time trying to get this to work.  Hoping someone has an idea as to what I am doing incorrectly here.  What I have is a very simple button and codebehind really nothing extravagant.

Here is my button. :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Width="60px" Text="Save" Enabled="False"></asp:Button>
```

Here is the server side event header. :

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
```

Again any ideas are greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried jQuery **event.preventDefault()** ??

Comment: Can you elaborate more on why javascript wouldn't work for you?

Comment: Well I think it has to do with the fact that I have a server side event interfering.  But I thought that you could have client and server side events occur at the same time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on button and disable it with javascript it is disabled on client and server side does not know it is disabled on client as server side checks the viewstate for control properties. If you want to keep it disabled after being clicked and postback then you have to disable it on both client and server.

**On client end**

```
$('#<%= btnSave.ClientID %>').click(function() {
         this.disabled = true;
    });
```

**On server end**

```
btnSave.enable = false
```

Comment: This worked, but I think my issue was that I was testing this with a breakpoint on my server side event.  I think that breakpoint was allowing me to click away.  I removed this breakpoint and this seemed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

client:

```
var buttonPressed = false;
```

server:

```
btnSave.OnClientClick = "if (buttonPressed) return false else buttonPressed = true; return true;"
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
 $('#yourButtonId').click(function() {
         $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more clever solution:
Server:

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Width="60px" 
Text="Save" Enabled="False" OnClientClick="return preventDblClick()" ></asp:Button>
```

Client:

```
var dbl = 0;
function preventDblClick() {
    if (dbl < 1) {
        dbl += 1;
        return true;

    } else {
        return false;

    }
}
```